# Reference dialog hyperlink configuration

Tags: 7, entities, forms

Can anyone please direct me on how to configure [References Dialog](http://drupal.org/project/references_dialog) so that instead of just returning the titles of my node as plain text, they are returned as hyperlinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, References Dialog only add links for add/edit/search.

If it's the display of a referenced node that you want to change, just change the field's format (under Manage Display) to "Title, as link".

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question but in case anyone is searching for an alternative of References Dialog module, try [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form)